# What event will fire if the textarea not being focus?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there any event will fire if the textarea is not focus anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onblur i think fires on an element that loses focus.  Check this out

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Answer (score 1):

That would be the `blur`, which is the opposite of `focus`.